# ModelClientValidationRule Class usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

When I mouseover `ModelClientValidationRule` class Visual Studio information box says:

**"This type/member supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."**

However, in almost all custom validation samples, `ModelClientValidationRule` is used.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I doing anything wrong?

No, you are not doing anything wrong. You could use the class directly even though it would be more appropriate to subclass it and have your `IClientValidatable` implementations returning your specific custom client validation rule. For example there's the `ModelClientValidationRequiredRule` which was specifically defined to handle the `"required"` client validation rule. The implementation is pretty trivial:

```
public class ModelClientValidationRequiredRule : ModelClientValidationRule
{
    public ModelClientValidationRequiredRule(string errorMessage)
    {
        base.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        base.ValidationType = "required";
    }
}
```

In your custom implementations you could of course include some other information.

Comment: Thank you Darin! Great assistance as usual ^_^